# Calculate difference in dates (in days) between group A and the row above it for each id

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

Here is a my `df` (data.frame):

```
      id   group     date
[1]    1     B    2000-01-01
[2]    1     B    2001-02-11  
[3]    1     A    2001-04-06   
[4]    2     C    2000-02-01
[5]    2     A    2001-01-01
[6]    2     B    2004-11-12 
    ...
```

The data.frame has been arranged by id and date.
I would like to calculate difference in dates (in days) between group A and the row above it for each id. In my data, every group A has a row above it for the same id.

The results that I am interest in will look something like this

```
      id       days
[1]    1        54  
[2]    2       335
    ...
```

Please advise

Thanks.

Comment: Please always mark the best answer for you with the "answered" tag if one answer solves your question as requested to close the question and document the result. THX :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it's already sorted, you can just do:

```
dft %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(diff_days = difftime(date, lag(date))) %>%
  filter(group == "A") %>%
  select(diff_days)
```

which gives:

```
     id diff_days
  <int>    <time>
1     1   54 days
2     2  335 days
```

Comment: @Sotos nope. didn't notice your answer while I was posting. Though your code is more robust, I admit. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

#make sure "date" has the appropriate class
df$date <- as.POSIXct(df$date, format = '%Y-%m-%d')

df %>% 
 group_by(id) %>%
 mutate(diff1 = c(NA, round(diff.difftime(date, units = 'days')))) %>% 
 filter(group == 'A') %>%
 select(id, diff1)

#Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
#Groups: id [2]

#     id diff1
#  <int> <dbl>
#1     1    54
#2     2   335
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, diff1 :=  c(NA, round(diff.difftime(date,
    units = 'days'), 0)), id][group=="A"][, c("id", "diff1"), with = FALSE]
#   id diff1
#1:  1    54
#2:  2   335
```